# neo4j_ something went wrong "RangeError. invalid string length" and the application cannot recover

Tags: neo4j

I use neo4j desktop in linux (ubuntu 20.04) when i loaded the csv file in huge size (44 megabyte) appear this error:
something went wrong "RangeError. invalid string length" and the application cannot recover as seen in this pecture:

The Used Code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Email-EuAll.csv' as line
WITH toInteger(line.source) AS Source, toInteger(line.destination) AS Destination
MERGE (a:person {name:Source})
MERGE (b:person {name:Destination})
MERGE (a)-[:Freind ]-(b)
RETURN *
```

[image]

Comment: There is some string within your csv, that is too large to process.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your statement?

It could also be that you tried to return too much data to neo4j browser? Just return nothing or count(*)

You can also try to run your statement in `cypher-shell` to see if it works there and narrow down the issue.

Comment: I inseted the used code...?